# Excel 2013 - open network location from data in 2 different cells

Tags: excel, vba

I want to use the combined data from 2 cells and then search for that particular folder on my network.

The structure is as follows:

- column B: **company name**
- column C: **part number**

The combined path would be something like:

```
\\ds2\data\customer\customer docs\${COMPANY_NAME}\${PART_NUMBER}
```

The expected result is a Windows Explorer view with all the folders with that part number.

See the [`following image`](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N4vTT.gif) for an example.

Comment: Do you need the Explorer view to open, or would a listing of the files in that directory suffice?

Comment: Listing of the files may be okay. Thanks for answering

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't open up explorer, but gives you a list of clickable links of the matching directories that you can follow to that folder

```
'this assumes there is a sheet named "Results" with a header in row 1
'output is a list of links on the results page matching that part
Sub GetFileList()
Const BaseFilePath As String = "C:\Test\" '"\ds2\data\customer\customer docs\"
Sheets("Results").Rows("2:100000").Clear
FilePath = BaseFilePath & Sheets("Search").Cells(1, 1) & "\" 'cells(1,1) has the company, adjust as necessary
FileSearch = "*" & Sheets("Search").Cells(1, 2) & "*" 'cells(1,2) has the part, adjust as necessary
r = 2
folderresult = Dir(FilePath & FileSearch, vbDirectory)
While folderresult <> ""
    Sheets("Results").Cells(r, 1) = FilePath & folderresult
    Sheets("Results").Hyperlinks.Add Anchor:=Sheets("Results").Cells(r, 1), Address:= _
        FilePath & folderresult, TextToDisplay:=FilePath & folderresult
    folderresult = Dir$
    r = r + 1
Wend
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi neuralgroove, can you provide an excel file with this code - I'm not sure how to implement. thank you

Comment: What seems to be the problem? This code will do what you were asking for, but it needs to be adjusted to your sheet (the one from your picture, the cell references need to be changed for your situation..in my example its looking in `cells(1,1)` for the company name, but in your sheet it might be `cells(1,4)`. After that you need a sheet named "Results" for the output

Comment: Basically mine is set up to look for the Company in Column A and the Part Number in Column B, in the first row. If you want it to work on multiple rows, then the row number will need to be supplied to the sub